# fitsSystemWindows in android studio layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio

Question: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in layout is not being taken into account in android studio layout preview. Why is this so and how can i make it show correctly in layout preview?

I am using a theme with the following flag

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

I have a layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is how it look like in preview
[image]

This is how it look on device
[image]

As you can see, "Hello World!" is overlapped by system bar in layout preview (`android:fitsSystemWindows` is not working here) but is positioned below system bar on device (`android:fitsSystemWindows` is working here)

Comment: Looks like an Android Studio bug.

Comment: @Zoe I am unable to find any information on this. Do you have a link to this issue on their issue tracker?

Comment: Doesn't look like it's been reported. I'm gonna see if I can reproduce it, if I can you should create an issue for it (if it is reproducable, that means it is mostly a bug and not a glitch caused by the local runtime)

Comment: Can't reproduce in AS 3.0 stable

Comment: @Zoe alright thanks. I guess now i just need to wait for someone to come along and answer this question. Anytime now...

Comment: I still have this bug in AS 3.0